# Могут ли быть авторские слова в виде придаточного предложения?

Tags: грамотная-речь, прямая-речь

*Как говорит руководитель театра, новая сцена была необходима:

– Чтобы больше артистов выходило на сцену. Чтобы проверяли сценическое пространство не только в размере шесть на четыре или шесть на шесть метров.*

Можно ли **так** оформить прямую речь?

Или нужно **обязательно** таким образом:

*Как говорит руководитель театра, новая сцена была необходима.

– Чтобы больше артистов выходило на сцену. Чтобы проверяли сценическое пространство не только в размере шесть на четыре или шесть на шесть метров, - говорит он.*

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, Вам можно оформить так:

*Как говорит руководитель театра, новая сцена была необходима, "чтобы больше артистов выходило на сцену, чтобы проверяли сценическое пространство не только в размере шесть на четыре или шесть на шесть метров".*

Правда, здесь слово сцена дважды повторяется, так что лучше в первом случае заменить, потому что второй уже в цитате.

Answer (score 2):

Прямая речь не может быть продолжением слов автора, она должна быть автономна.

Например:

*На вопрос, почему была необходима новая сцена, руководитель театра отвечал так:

– Чтобы больше артистов выходило на сцену. Чтобы проверяли сценическое пространство не только в размере шесть на четыре или шесть на шесть метров.*

*Руководитель театра говорил:

– Новая сцена была необходима, чтобы больше артистов выходило на сцену, чтобы проверяли сценическое пространство не только в размере шесть на четыре или шесть на шесть метров.*

Слово "как" в таком случае неуместно, оно обычно предворяет косвенную речь или цитату.

Думаю, вам лучше отказаться от прямой речи и следовать совету @Наталья

Answer (score 2):

**По мнению руководителя театра, новая сцена была необходима. "Чтобы больше артистов выходило на сцену. Чтобы проверяли сценическое пространство не только в размере шесть на четыре или шесть на шесть метров", – считает он.**

Первая часть – это пересказ, а вторая часть – дословное высказывание, поэтому они разделены. Лучше оформить прямую речь в строку, так как это не диалог.

Comment: Решение нестандартное, но очень удачное, на мой взгляд.